# Key for storing user info

Tags: nosql, md5, key-value

My app have the authorization module. I use cassandra as nosql keyvalue db. As key for user I use MD5(username+password). Is it good way? What are pros and cons?

TIA!

Answer (score 0):

This is not related to Cassandra but the short answer is: don't go with that md5 scheme. It's easy to do a brute-force attack. Use **bcrypt** (see http://codahale.com/how-to-safely-store-a-password/ for a good explanation)

Comment: Bruteforce attack can be used when somebody have access to application db. But if smb. have this access - he(or she) don't need search for a password he(or she) can take necessary information from db. And it'll be not a trivial task (because he needs to understand how identify necessary user.

Comment: There are a lot of "don't user md5"-like messages. But nobody give full explanation about cases when this bruteforce can be applied.